# How to write this T-SQL in LINQ to sQL?

Tags: .net, linq, t-sql, linq-to-sql

```
select * from table1 where pkey1 in
(select pkey2 from table2 where column1='abc')
```

Where pkey1 and pkey2 are both int columns.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

something like:

```
from t1 in table1
let x = from t2 in table2 where t2.column1.Equals("abc") select t2
where t1.pkey1.Equals(x.pkey2)
select t1;
```

and you ending up know what `let` helps you to do :)

Comment: You will probably run into some problems when you try to call `pkey2` off of `x` though, since `x` is an `IQueryable`

Comment: That's exactly what I did!  I suppose it would work if the sub-query only returned one value, but on the data I tested it on, it returned multiple values and x wound up being an `IQueryable` and wouldn't even compile...nonetheless... *runs off to try again* ^_^

Comment: Huh...I must be testing it on some strange data since I still cannot get it to compile.  It keeps typing `x` as an `IQueryable`, but if you've seen it run on your box that's good enough for me!

Answer (score 2):

Not a LINQ answer, but a perfectly valid LINQ-to-SQL one:

```
var results = ctx.ExecuteQuery<Table1>(@"
    select * from table1 where pkey1 in
    (select pkey2 from table2 where column1='abc')").ToList();
```

You don't *have* to hand over control of every query to LINQ; indeed, in many cases a well-written custom TSQL query can be far more efficient that one generated from LINQ-to-SQL. Which isn't a *criticism* of LINQ-to-SQL (it does a great job for the majority of queries that are simple etc).

Comment: is there a simple technique like this in order to get multiple tables? or we have to handle with the Reader and itenerating with `reader.NextResult()` is the only option?

Comment: @balexandre - pretty much, but note that you can use `ctx.Translate<TResult>(DbDataReader)` to get LINQ to do the object mapping for you.

Comment: Marc, while you can execute straight queries, it does create a maintenance nightmare when columns are dropped. Updating all those queries can be a pain.

Comment: Agreed. I wouldn't use `.ExecuteQuery` in this particular scenario - it's a fairly simple LINQ operation which L2SQL should have no trouble translating to native SQL. But take your point.

Answer (score 2):

```
var query = from a in db.table1
            join b in db.table2 on a.pkey1 equals b.pkey2
            where b.column1 == "abc"
            select a;
```

Comment: should be `==` and not `=` ... and shound't we always use `.Equals` instead `==` ?

Comment: Thanks - `=` updated. w.r.t. `.Equals`, since we're comparing primitive values (string, string), i would be using `==`. No need to worry about references here, which is the main use for `.Equals`.

Comment: Although he didn't ask for it, I'd personally use a case-insensitive string comparison.  Also, isn't it `"abc"`, not `'abc'`?

Comment: @Merlyn Morgan-Graham - yes, i would use an insensitive comparison too. There are too many unknowns to this question - hence the simple answers. And yes, thanks for the `''` mention - think it's time for me to go to bed. :)

Comment: I think you also need a select clause in there somewhere... ^_^

Answer (score 2):

```
from t in table1
join u in table2 on t.pkey1 equals u.pkey2
where u.column1 == "abc"
select t;
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is another possible query:

```
var q = from t2 in table2.Where(x => x.column1 == "abc")
        from t in table1.Where(x => x.pkey1 == t2.pkey2)
        select t;
```

You might need to call `Distinct()` on the results depending on how you want to use it.  The generated SQL is equivalent to:

```
SELECT [t1].*
FROM table2 AS [t2], table1 AS [t1]
WHERE ([t2].[column1] = 'abc') AND ([t1].[pkey1] = [t2].[pkey2])
```